# kivy function not accessing self when called

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building an app to extract data from a web page, parse that info, then update some labels with that info. The function is triggered from a clock schedule. The problem is that when I attempt to take the string I've concatenated from the parser and update the label, I'm getting "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'flabel0'. Without dropping in the entire .py and .kv files, here are the relevant bits:

```
class blBox(BoxLayout):
    flabel0 = ObjectProperty(None)
    flabel1 = ObjectProperty(None)  ## etc
    
    def flight_up(self):
        (routine here that scrapes data first, puts it into a text file, which works)

        with open("flt.txt", "r") as fh:
        (parse info and concatenate into string named "tstr", which works)
            if golabel == 1:  ##not all lines in the text file are valid
                if lblcount == 0:  ##pick which label to update
                    self.flabel0.text = tstr  <<-------------------------------- throws the error here

    Clock.schedule_interval(flight_up, 30)

.kv code
<BackgroundColor@Widget>
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    font_name: 'c:\Windows\Fonts\erasdemi.ttf'

<FLLabel@Label+BackgroundColor>
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_normal: 'white.png'   ## a little white square
    background_color: .8, .8, 1, 1
    font_name: 'c:\Windows\Fonts\ltypeb.ttf'
    font_size: '22sp'
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'center'
    texture_size: self.size
    text_size: self.size

<blBox>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    flabel0: flt0
    flabel1: flt1 #etc
    BoxLayout:  ## buttons and labels for left side
    BoxLayout:  ## buttons and labels for right side
        id: rightside
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FLlabel:
            id: flt0
            text: 'Arrival'
            background_color: .9, .9, 1, 1

        FLlabel:
            id: flt1
            text: 'Arrival'
            background_color: .8, .8, .9, 1
```

The error seems to say that 'self' is a float object? Let me know if any of this isn't clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `ids` assigned, you can just use them in your `flight_up()` method. Also, the `flight_up()` method must accept a `dt` argument (which is the time delta) or a general `*args`. So your `flight_up()` can look like:

```
def flight_up(self, *args):
    # (routine here that scrapes data first, puts it into a text file, which works)

    with open("flt.txt", "r") as fh:
        # (parse info and concatenate into string named "tstr", which works)
        if golabel == 1:  ##not all lines in the text file are valid
            if lblcount == 0:  ##pick which label to update
                self.ids.flt0.text = tstr
```

Also, setting up the `Clock.schedule_once()` outside of a method of the `blBox` class results in `flight_up` being called as a class method (no `self` argument).

You can correct this by adding an `__init__()` method that does the scheduling:

```
class blBox(BoxLayout):
    flabel0 = ObjectProperty(None)
    flabel1 = ObjectProperty(None)  ## etc
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.flight_up, 30)
        super(blBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

and, of course, remove the other call to `Clock`.

Comment: Bingo! Moving it to the __init__ was the fix. Nice explanation too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def flight_up(self):
```

to

```
def flight_up(self, arg):
```

Maybe then

```
Clock.schedule_interval(flight_up, 30)
```

will pass 30 as arg

Comment: Thanks for responding! When I add arg, I get the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'". When I change it to *arg or *args, then I get the original error again.